# Typescript and CSS-modules types

Tags: typescript, css-modules

I want to use not a dumb mock for CSS modules but real types so I use webpack plugin [typings-for-css-modules-loader](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader)

for simple css

```
.foo { color: red; }
.bar { color: green; }
```

it can generate `example.css.d.ts` declaration

```
export interface ILocals {
  'foo': string;
  'bar': string;
}
export interface IExampleCss {
  locals: ILocals;
  'foo': string;
  'bar': string;
}

declare const styles: IExampleCss

export default styles;
```

so in my code I able to use it like so

```
import css from './example.css';

const { locals } = css;

<div className={locals.foo}>Red</div>
<div className={css.bar}>Green</div>
```

and VSCode knows that locals.**foo** and css.**bar** members

I try to write a function which is able to get any css definitions in typescript as an input parameter

```
interface IStringHash {
    [key: string]: string;
}
interface ICSSLocals {
    locals: IStringHash;
    [key: string]: string | IStringHash;
}

interface ISomeInterface {
    renderComponent: (css: ICSSLocals): React.ReactNode
}

const myFunction = (css: IExampleCss) => {
    return (
        <div key="1" className={css.locals.foo}>Red</div>
        <div key="2" className={css.bar}>Green</div>
    )
}

const MyRenderer: ISomeInterface = {
    renderComponent: myFunction
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

I get the error:

`[ts]
Type 'IExampleCss' is not assignable to type 'ICSSLocals'.
  Type 'IExampleCss' is not assignable to type 'ICSSLocals'.
    Types of property 'locals' are incompatible.
      Type 'ILocals' is not assignable to type 'IStringHash'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'ILocals'.`

What is wrong?

I've wrote a relevant sample in [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Declaration%20with%20generics%0D%0Ainterface%20IStringHash%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ICSSModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20locals%3A%20IStringHash%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20IStringHash%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20returnObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISomeInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20renderComponent%3A%20(css%3A%20ICSSModule)%20%3D>%20returnObject%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20usage%20with%20certain%20realisation%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ILocals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'foo'%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20'bar'%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IExampleCss%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20locals%3A%20ILocals%3B%0D%0A%20%20'foo'%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20'bar'%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%20%3D%20(css%3A%20IExampleCss)%3A%20returnObject%20%3D>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20css.locals.foo%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20css.bar%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20MyRenderer%3A%20ISomeInterface%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20renderComponent%3A%20myFunction%0D%0A%7D%3B)

```
// Declaration with generics
interface IStringHash {
    [key: string]: string;
}
interface ICSSModule {
    locals: IStringHash;
    [key: string]: string | IStringHash;
}

interface returnObject {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

interface ISomeInterface {
    renderComponent: (css: ICSSModule) => returnObject
}

// usage with certain realisation
export interface ILocals {
  'foo': string;
  'bar': string;
}
export interface IExampleCss {
  locals: ILocals;
  'foo': string;
  'bar': string;
}

const myFunction = (css: IExampleCss): returnObject => {
    return {
        a: css.locals.foo,
        b: css.bar
    }
}

const MyRenderer: ISomeInterface = {
    renderComponent: myFunction
      ^^^^^^^
};
```

here is the error:

`[ts]
Type '(css: IExampleCss) => returnObject' is not assignable to type '(css: ICSSModule) => returnObject'.
  Types of parameters 'css' and 'css' are incompatible.
    Type 'ICSSModule' is not assignable to type 'IExampleCss'.
      Property ''foo'' is missing in type 'ICSSModule'.
   (property) ISomeInterface.renderComponent: (css: ICSSModule) => returnObject`

Comment: Can you give more info what are you doing with `myFunction` ? Taking 'any css declaration' seems not much better than just using `any` type.

Comment: @Ski I've fixed function above

Comment: @Ski I need type suggestions an show error if there are

Comment: I'm confused: if `myFunction` accesses `css.locals.foo` and `css.bar`, then it will only work for CSS modules that have classes named `foo` and `bar`.  So why are you trying to declare `myFunction` as taking any CSS module?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I use some loaders for servrer & browser usage styles - so there it's not so important

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all.  To try to clarify my question: The type `(css: ICSSModule) => returnObject` is not accurate for `myFunction` because it would allow the CSS file `.baz { color: blue; }` to be passed to `myFunction`, but `myFunction` would not work as intended: it would access class names `foo` and `bar` that do not exist.  So why do you want to use this inaccurate type?  It might help if you add more information to the question about the role that `myFunction` plays within your application.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to only require what you need of the interface and not more. So looks like `bar` should not be in  `ILocals` and `foo` should not be in `IExampleCss`

```
export interface ILocals {
  'foo': string;   
//  'bar': string; <--
}
export interface IExampleCss {
  locals: ILocals;
  // 'foo': string; <--
  'bar': string;
}

const myFunction = (css: IExampleCss): returnObject => {
    return {
        a: css.locals.foo,
        b: css.bar
    }
}
```

Sidenote: for simple cases you don't have to declare return type - it will be inferred. And if you need the type of function return value, you can use `ReturnType<myFunction>`.

Comment: `css.locals.foo` is used for sample to show that any item can be accessed directly or through `locals`

Comment: Sorry mixed this up, `foo` should stay, `bar` should go

Answer (score 0):

try out this webpack loader: [React-css-components loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rcc-loader)

configuration example with nextjs

```
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    const rccLoaderRule = {
      test: /\.module\.scss$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'rcc-loader',
          options: {
            enabled: !!dev && isServer,
            exportStyleOnly: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }

    config.module.rules = config.module.rules ?? []
    config.module.rules.push(rccLoaderRule)

    return config
  }
}
```